# Как преобразовать массив float в массив long?

Tags: java

Есть ли возможность сделать это без перечисления? Просто с помощью какого-нибудь приведения.

Примерно так:

```
float[] b;
long a[] = (long)b[];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать Guava библиотеку: https://github.com/google/guava

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;
import com.google.common.primitives.Floats;

float[] b = new float[5];
long a[] = Longs.toArray(Floats.asList(b));
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что наверняка в Guava делается это так же с использованием перечислений (через for, etc). А потому, вы можете реализовать свой метод с использованием перечислений и вызывать его.

Answer (score 3):

Если под перечислением подразумевается цикл `for`:

```
long[] a = new long[b.length];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
    a[i] = (long)b[i];
}
```

то вместо цикла можно воспользоваться Java 8 Stream:

```
long[] a = IntStream.range(0, b.length)
        .mapToDouble(i -> b[i])
        .mapToLong(e -> (long)e)
        .toArray();
```

Однако простым такое решение назвать сложно. Если бы массив `b` был типа `double`, то код был бы короче и проще:

```
long[] a = DoubleStream.of(b)
        .mapToLong(e -> (long)e)
        .toArray();
```

Более простое и короткое решение возможно с использованием сторонних библиотек (таких как Guava).